# Is AWS Amplify the only way to make SDK calls to Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to integrate Cognito Authorizers into an existing application that is using API Gateway to authorize requests.

The documentation insists on using AWS Amplify to make these calls, but I'm not sure that this fits in well with the existing architecture since Amplify seems to have its own way of making API requests, and I'm worried that it would mandate having to change all of the existing API requests...

So my question is if there are more readily integratable solutions to this problem, or if my concerns are unfounded.

Comment: There is an example of what your describing in the AWS documents, just [follow this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/)

Answer (score 3):

There are several SDK's that can be used with Cognito.

You can use the AWS js SDK to make low level API calls but you will lose the benefits that the Cognito Client Side SDKS provide like session management, caching of tokens and SRP calculations.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html

You can also use the Cognito Identity SDK which Amplify uses under the hood:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js

The Auth SDK if you are going to be integrating with the OAuth endpoints, which is now deprecated but can still be used or referenced, Amplify also uses or has similar functionality.
https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-auth-js

And then finally Amplify which is the go to, feature rich client side SDK which for the majority of usecases should be the SDK of choice in my opinion.

Comment: I would say don't use deprecated SDK's :)